# Select words without indentation in text editor

Tags: python, text-editor

Currently you can select a line with the `select_line` command. The problem is that you select the complete line, with the indentations.

I'd like to know how I can select only the words of the current line, to integrate it in a pie please.

Comment: It would be better if you had posted the relevant code along with the question. In case you have the selected line in a string call `string.lstrip()` to get rid of the leading whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def execute(self, context):

    bpy.ops.text.move(type='LINE_BEGIN')
    bpy.ops.text.move(type='NEXT_WORD')
    bpy.ops.text.move_select(type='LINE_END')
    return {'FINISHED'}
```

This selects whitespace at the end of the line.